# Can we add torques on different parts of body about a point and calculate total torque about that point?

Tags: classical-mechanics, torque

Give proof also . I was doubtful as in a question . Torque due to a couple was calculated using adding torque of the couple due to different parts of the body .

Comment: We can add the torques as vectors and find the total torque about a point. I don't quite understand your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You always have to define some reference point to calculate torque about.

Comment: You can’t prove a definition (of *total torque*). What you *can* do is prove how it relates to total angular momentum.